# How to properly install libsvm-3.11?

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I'm using libvm-3.11. I downloaded it [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm) and extracted. Then I set path in Matlab. After that whenever I run my program, it gives the same error always.

```
??? Invalid MEX-file 'E:\Gomu\Gomu General\final yr
Project\proj\libsvm-3.11\windows\svmtrain.mexw32': The specified module could not be found.

Error in ==> trysvm at 6
svmStruct = svmtrain(T,TrainMat,'showplot',true);
```

What should I do?

Comment: Not do discourage you, but a better place to ask this would be the Stack Exchange, not DSP Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks for the information. I will ask it there.

Answer (score 0):

read the README file and compile the C files using mex. Mex files are platform/MATLAB version dependent. The binary download doesn't always work for everybody.